# ms-access record/page level locking

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

i am baffled as to what is happening with the database

i have a split front and back end access database

every user has their own front end

sometimes some users are able to edit the data and sometimes not. i don't know how to explain this

here are the settings:
[alt text http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/5779/47047459.png](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/5779/47047459.png)

anybody know what is going on here>?

Comment: I used to create these type of apps all the time.  The most consistent way I found was to control update, inserts, and deletes manually within classes behind the scene as opposed to letting the forms do the work.  That way there was rarely any locking issues.  This may have not been optimal but it worked.

Comment: that is a great point, but do know what the heck is the prob here

Comment: So what happens when the user is unable to edit a record?  Any error message(s)?   Are they possibly working in the same records?  Does the record selector show a black stop sign instead of the right facing triangle?  Is this on the same form or can one form update data while another form can't.   I disagree with buckbova's approach of not using bound forms as I've never had any such problems.

Comment: tony, there are no messages at all and nothing is different at all except for the fact that when they try to edit any record they simply are not able to, nothing happens

Comment: What about the record selector?  What does it show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in your screen shot, the settings are default to no locks. However, the settings in that screen are ONLY for the defaults WHEN YOU create a NEW form.  In other words modifying the settings in that screen will NOT effect existing forms in your application that you've already created.

The exception to the above a course is the global setting of using row locking, that is a system-wide setting.

Again:
Those options above of "no locks", "all records", and "edited record" are ONLY defaults for new forms that you create. They DO NOT change the behavior of existing forms within your application.

So you must STILL make changes on a forms by form's basis within your application, you'll find this setting in the data tab of the forms property sheet for locking behavour.

However after having said and done all of the above, I don't think that the above settings is the problem that you're experiencing.

I suspect your real problem is when an access database is opened, a separate temporary "locking" file that manages the users collisions and record locks is created (and keep in mind that this temporary locking file is created in the same directory as where the shared data is, in this case your back end shared data folder)

What this means is when users who don't have CREATE FILE permissions in that shared back end folder means access will be force to open the data file  in READ ONLY mode ( if access cannot create that locking management file, then it defaults to read only mode).

What this means is when the first user who opens the database can't create that temporary separate locking file, then for the most part additional users coming into the database will also not be able to make modifications, and will also be in read only mode. This results in the perplexing troubleshooting issue of finding out that the order of what user FIRST opens the database in in a sense determined that the database will be read only.

This seems like a very strange problem indeed, but  becomes far more clear once the above temporary locking file mystery is explained.

In effect, to eliminate these problems, it means that all users need file creation rights to that share folder. In fact when they exit then the last one out will cause that temporary locking file to be deleted. Therefore all uses should have file deletion rights to that share folder also.

So during your troubleshooting and testing, make sure EVERY SINGLE user has wide open file permissions to that backend folder. If you don't do this, then you will find the order of users that open that file (and those without file creation rights) will in effect determine the Read-Only status of the database.

Comment: hi albert thank you very very much for this answer. this answer is very very good, but i do not think this is correct. i have checked that forms have the correct locking properties and i have checked all the users that use this DB, they are all able to delete stuff in the folder where the backend is.

Comment: Did you actually read Albert's answer? What you've just commented on is not actually the main point of his answer at all. Did you check the NTFS permissions on the folder where the database is stored or not?

Comment: FWIW, DELETE permission is actually not required. It will still work just fine without the LDB file being deleted, though that occasionally can cause problems if there's anything corrupted in the LDB file. My usual practice is to give administrators (i.e., the people responsible for database maintenance) full permissions and regular users just MODIFY permission.

Comment: david, yes, the problem is sometimes a user is able to edit data and sometimes that same user is locked from editing anything

Comment: And did you read Albert's answer? If so, did you not understand it?

Comment: Is there any reason why you have not accepted this answer when your other avatar appears to have done so? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397383/ms-access-2003-multi-users-application-any-other-way-than-granting-all-users-fu/3397429#3397429)