# MS Access 2003 multi-users application : Any other way than granting all users full windows permissions to the directory?

Tags: security, ms-access, ms-access-2003

Some users will use the database as read-only and some will need to add, delete and update records.

Now, users that will be read-only on the database also have the read-only rights as windows permissions on the backend directory. What happens obviously is that the backend becomes read-only.
I thought using the access security thingy would counter that but it seems not.

So my question is, is it something I am doing wrong or is there really no other way ?

Thanks for any input.

Edit : Just for clarification, what I mean is when a read only users use the database, the users that should be able to add, delete or update database can't.

Comment: If an mdb is r-o at system level, an app cannot bypass that, of course.

Comment: Thx Patrick but the users that are gonna add, delete and update do have the windows permissions to do so, off course. But they still can't do so when another user without the permissions are using it.

Comment: Jet/ACE files are written to even when the user doesn't make changes to the data, because Jet updates certain flags to show that the file was closed cleanly (and other things, too). All users, regardless of whether they are viewing or editing the data, need modify access to the file. You can remove DELETE permission on the folder, but that only really effects the LDB file.

Comment: Your edit has a seeming typo in it. Do you mean that when your read-only users open the database, the read/write users are read-only, too? How are they opening the database? Are they doing it with exclusive access? It definitely sounds like you've been overly strict on your NTFS permissions. Start with full control for everybody and if the problem goes away, the one permission you can remove is DELETE, but many experienced Access developers don't do that (it is really only relevant to the LDB file).

Comment: >> Do you mean that when your read-only users open the database, the read/write users are read-only, too?   Yes, I mean that. Thanks for the first comment, I think it may be as simple as that and now I understand. Since I can't really change the NTFS permissions easily so we're gonna try to just ask people to quit the application when there's an update coming. (For a while at least) otherwise I will do what's needed to give them more permissions without the DELETE one. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access user level security is not going to change the permissions on the folder. ULS can control what your users can do.

I understood your question, it implies that ULS could somehow modify the permissions that you have set too stringently. You must set the folder permissions so that all users have add & edit permissions.

Comment: My goal isn't to change the permissions on the folder, it's exactly the opposite. Please check the Edit I added to my question, I hope it helps clarify my problem.

Comment: I think you mean "modify" permissions, not add/edit (which don't really have meaning to the file system).